# How to share a DB connection pool in Python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, multiprocessing, connection-pooling

I'm using multiprocessing.Pool to execute some function. And in the function I need to connect to database (using sqlalchemy). I try to share the sqlalchemy connection pool to child processes by using multiprocessing.Queue, like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager

def process(data, queue):
    db = queue.get()
    with db.connect() as connection:
        # execute some query

data_list = [] # list of data I'm going to deal with
pool = Pool(8)
manager = Manager()
queue = manager.Queue()
db = sqlalchemy.create_engine()
for data in data_list:
    queue.put(db)
    pool.apply_async(func=process, args=(data, db)) # This is 1st way I try
    pool.apply_async(func=process, args=(data, queue)) # This is 2nd way I try
```

I try these two way, but they both raise error.

The first way would raise a `Broken Pipe Error` when executing `with db.connect() as connection`.

The second way it would raise a `Can't pickle local object 'create_engine.<locals>.connect'` error.

I search this problem and found some people said sharing connection pool to child processes is feasible, but how should I share the engine with multiprocess?

Comment: what is `data_list`, that has not been defined anywhere

Comment: @Charchit it's a list of data which I'm going to deal with, it's not related to the problem

Comment: which OS are you using? OSX? The code (first one) runs without error on Windows if the multiprocessing start method is "spawn"

Comment: @Charchit I'm running it on CentOS

Comment: Not knowing anything about sqlalchemy, I am not sure that `db` can be shared across processes. But assuming it is, it would have to be serializable using *pickle*. So why even bother passing it via a queue? You should then just pass it as an argument as in your first try. But you say the second way raises a pickle error (I think both ways should). Clearly, `db` is *not* shareable among processes the way you are doing it (you would need to create a special managed class that fields requests from processes).

Comment: And, for what it's worth, I believe you are getting the Broken Pipe Error because your program is terminating (and destroying the queue) before the submitted tasks (using `apply_async`) have completed. You would need to add calls to `pool.close(); pool.join()` to ensure the submitted tasks have completed before you terminate.

Comment: I looked into it today and seemingly the documentation has a [section](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html#using-connection-pools-with-multiprocessing-or-os-fork) on how to use sqlalchemy with multiprocessing. It basically confirms what has been said here, `Engine` cannot be pickled and you have to create new one for each child process. The reason why the code ran without error on my machine was because I had missed that there wasn't a `.get()` done on the pool workers that were started. After adding that, I got same error.

Comment: @Charchit Yeah the document is helpful, I think that's what I need, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @charchit's comment, [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html#using-connection-pools-with-multiprocessing-or-os-fork) is documentation about using sqlalchemy with multiprocessing